# LTC Pool With Friends?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin

Is there a way I could set up my LTC mining pool so that my friends could join? I've been having really good luck lately!

Answer (score 1):

[P2Pool](http://p2pool.org/)is a good way to do that. It can be hard to set up but is the best way to do it.